# java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /mdta/app/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map

Tags: jquery

In my web application, one of the JSP page is not opening in mobile view, while looking for its reason in log file then see that one `FileNotFoundException` for the file jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map is there. I delve further than I found this particular file is being referred in file jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, I deleted the line where jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map is written, I updated the main file as well but nothing works and still the same error. Can someone please help me to get rid of this? Any help will be appreciated.
I am attaching the screenshot of logs of error and JS file for better understanding.

Note: I am very new here, I tried making the question crisp and clear but in case anyone needs further info then please let me know.

Error Log:

```
WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
ipp/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map (Log4JImpl.java, line 24) Lag->false the allowCurrentLoginUsers Flag->false the videoTollingFlag->false the violationsFlag->true the invoicesFlag->false (Log4JImpl.java, line 24)
L09W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter VectorCommonFilter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /mdta/app/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map
```

[image: JS File]

Comment: Please post code and log as text, not as images.

Comment: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed. ipp/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map (Log4JImpl.java, line 24)
Lag->false the allowCurrentLoginUsers Flag->false the videoTollingFlag->false the violationsFlag->true the invoicesFlag->false (Log4JImpl.java, line 24)
L09W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter VectorCommonFilter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /mdta/app/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map

Comment: First line of JS file: /*! jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 | Git HEAD hash: 9d9a42a <> 2014-02-28T17:32:01Z | (c) 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */  last line of JS file: //# sourceMappingURL=jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map. Having boundation of limited text thats why not able to post the whole text.

Comment: That was meant to be [edit]ed into the text of your question. A comment does not allow as much text and lacks the capability of formatting blocks of code. Please [edit] your question and add the full text of your JavaScript to allow others to reproduce your problem. Please don't forget to format the code as such (ctrl/k).